# Does the Ward-Takahashi identity work for a virtual photon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles, ward-identity

In the reaction of the transformation of an electron pair into a muon pair is performed Ward–Takahashi identity. Why if there is no interaction with a real photon?

Comment: The Ward identity is the statement that the longitudinal d.o.f of an external photon is unphysical and disappears from the S-matrix. You need to have an external photon, attached to whatever process.